# Find the difference between two dates Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, datediff, teradatasql

I have a dataset with ID, Date and Sts

```
 ID     SDate         EDate       Sts
101     7/18/2023      7/18/2023  01  
101     7/19/2023      7/18/2023  01
101     7/20/2023      7/20/2023  02
101     7/21/2023      7/21/2023  03
```

I need to calculate the number of days between

```
   When ‘SDate=‘Edate and STS ne ‘01’ - 
   When ‘SDate=‘EDate and STS=‘01’
```

In the above case it should be 7/20/2023-7/18/2023 = 3 days

I have created separate datasets for STS=‘01’ and STS ne ‘01’ and joining on ID and look for date difference > 0

Is there an efficient way using ‘Windows functions?

Thanks

Comment: Why pick the 3rd row over the 4th row for the non-01 part?

Comment: That’s the first STS chance from 01 to 02

Comment: Please edit your question to more clearly explain the intent. It's not clear why you would create separate datasets and join. Are you aggregating by ID or joining on conditions in addition to ID? You mention window functions which sort of implies all the data would need to be in a single table / relation.

Comment: I would create two datasets one for 01 and other one is for ne 01. Then join these two tables based on ID and subtract STS 01 date from STS ne 01 dataset and use minimum difference value.. I don’t want to go in this route

Comment: I don't use teradata, but does it support `conditional aggregation`? Something similar to this... `select 
 id, 
 min(case when sdate = edate and sts <> '01' then edate else null end) - 
 min(case when sdate = edate and sts = '01' then sdate else null end) as diff
from table1
group by id;`

Comment: Some more detail would help. Since we don't know what these fields or their values mean, or the use case there's some ambiguity. If for every sts = 01 record, you want the different between it's end date and the end date of the next sts <> 01 that is doable. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: For every Sts=01 record when both the dates (SDate and EDate) are equal. Similarly for <>01 when both the dates are equal